# Rails - How can I generate thumbnails on-the-fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rmagick

I am looking for a way to generate thumbnails of my uploaded images on the fly. I have a product model that looks kind of like this:

```
    class Product
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Paperclip

      has_mongoid_attached_file :picture
    end
```

I basically just want to upload one high-res picture, which I can then use for thumbnails, the main image and also the high-res picture for fancy-box etc..

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if ImageMagick has a gem, but that (or something like that) would be the way to go.

Comment: I find dragonfly quite good for this

Comment: As far as I know, Dragonfly does not work with MongoId, does it?

Comment: as long as it's activemodel compliant you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

There are many attributes you can set for paperclip attached_file.

e.g.,

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :picture,
    :styles => {
      :original => ['1920x1680>', :jpg],
      :small    => ['100x100#',   :jpg],
      :medium   => ['250x250',    :jpg],
      :large    => ['500x500>',   :jpg]
    }
```

You can set the :styles attributes with many versions of the image with the sizes and formats you want.

Check [here](https://github.com/meskyanichi/mongoid-paperclip) for more details. You do need image processor like RMagick / Imagemagick though.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this solution is, that the mages are generated upon upload. This kind of sucks when the image dimensions change during the development process or if another view is added with different dimensions ect...

Comment: Thumbnail size changes during development are no problem. You can always regenerate all thumbnails using "rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails CLASS=<your class here>".